# How do I remove an item from nested array using swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

Suppose I had the following state item and I wanted to remove the item within the nested data array using onDelete. I can manually enter the index using

```
.onDelete { indexSet in
            items**[1]**.data.remove(atOffsets: indexSet) }
```

and it works for that particular array but what do I put instead of hard wiring the index [1]. Is there a better way to do this?

```
struct Item: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var data: [Datr]
}

struct Datr: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var number: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case number = "number"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State fileprivate var items = [
        Item(id: 1, data: [Datr(id: 1, number: "one"), Datr(id: 2, number: "two")]),
        Item(id: 2, data: [Datr(id: 1, number: "three"), Datr(id: 2, number: "four")])
        ]
             
  var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(items) {
            item in
            ForEach(item.data) { item2 in
                Text(item2.number)
            }
        }.onDelete { indexSet in
            items[1].data.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks :)

I thought maybe there way to get the indices out of indexSet , but couldn't find anything?

Comment: indexset is an array of indices you can loop through them to get each

Comment: thanks @loremipsum . I've got it working ->.                                              .onDelete { indexSet in
            for n in indexSet {
                items[n].data.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            }

Comment: Glad to hear, you can post your solution as an answer and mark it as such. It can help other people that have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

@loremipsum posted that you can loop through the IndexSet as an Array and get the item's index. So in the case of deleting an item that is nested in an array you can use the following:

```
List {
        ForEach(items) {
            item in
            ForEach(item.data) { item2 in
                Text(item2.number)
            }
        }.onDelete { indexSet in
            for n in indexSet {
                items[n].data.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            }
            
      }
```